# Apache (httpd) service is running on Ec2 at port 80 and curl localhost:80 shows the content of index.html file located at /var/www/html

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

Apache (httpd) service is running on RedHat EC2 instance at port 80 and command "curl localhost:80" shows the content of index.html file located at /var/www/html of the apache server.

Below is the output of command "service httpd status", which shows that apache is running and listening on port 80 as well.

```
 Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-01-23 16:25:44 UTC; 24s ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
 Main PID: 1651 (httpd)
   Status: "Running, listening on: port 80"
```

```
I have opened port 80 for http on my EC2 instance.But when i try to access
```

the apache using http://<Public IP of EC2 Instance>:80

then browser gives message

"This site can’t be reached".

Please let me know why i am unable to access apache using 
http://<Public IP of EC2 Instance>:80
and what would be fix to enable me to access it.

```
curl localhost:80
returns output as below
hello world
```

```
curl Public_IP_OF_EC2:80
returns output as below
curl: (7) Failed to connect to *.*.***.172 port 80: No route to host
```

The security group rule for my Ec2 instance is to accept all traffic which means port 80 for http is open on my EC2 instance.

Comment: Can someone please answer this question